# Foreingkey não é atualizada

Tags: entity-framework

Não estou conseguindo alterar um campo foreingkey no banco de dados. No meu caso, os objetos (TipoEndereco = 3 e Endereco = 2) já existem.

Segue o modelo (simples):

```
public class Endereco
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Cep { get; set; }
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string Uf { get; set; }
    public TipoEndereco Tipo { get; set; }
}

public class TipoEndereco
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Estou alterando os dados de endereço seguinte forma:

```
        TipoEnderecoBLO teblo = new TipoEnderecoBLO();
        EnderecoBLO eblo = new EnderecoBLO();

        TipoEndereco te = new TipoEndereco();
        te.Id = 3;

        Endereco e = new Endereco();
        e.Bairro = "Casa Grande";
        e.Cep = "22.723-002";
        e.Cidade = "Rio de Janeiro";
        e.Logradouro = "Estrada do Mapuá";
        e.Uf = "RJ";
        e.Tipo = te;//aqui estou mudando o tipo de endereço
        e.Id = 2;
        eblo.Update(e);
```

Ao enviar o comando:

```
_context.Entry(endereco).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Alguns dados do endereço são alterados, mas o tipo de endereço (Tipo_Id) não é alterado no banco de dados.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está incorreto o modo com o qual você está atribuindo o Tipo de Endereço:

```
    TipoEndereco te = new TipoEndereco();
    te.Id = 3;
```

Há duas formas de fazer: ou você seleciona o Tipo de Endereço 3, ou você cria um tipo de endereço 3 e anexa ao contexto para ele ser observado.

Outra coisa é que o Endereço precisa ser selecionado antes de ser alterado.

#### Abordagem 1: Selecionando do contexto

```
    var te = contexto.TiposEndereco.FirstOrDefault(te => te.Id == 3);
    var e = contexto.Enderecos.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 2);

    e.Bairro = "Casa Grande";
    e.Cep = "22.723-002";
    e.Cidade = "Rio de Janeiro";
    e.Logradouro = "Estrada do Mapuá";
    e.Uf = "RJ";
    e.Tipo = te;//aqui estou mudando o tipo de endereço
    e.Id = 2;

    contexto.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
    contexto.SaveChanges();
```

#### Abordagem 2: Anexando ao contexto um objeto incompleto

```
    TipoEndereco te = new TipoEndereco();
    te.Id = 3;

    contexto.TiposEnderecos.Attach(te); // Dará erro se Id == 3 não existir.
    var e = contexto.Enderecos.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 2);

    Endereco e = new Endereco();
    e.Bairro = "Casa Grande";
    e.Cep = "22.723-002";
    e.Cidade = "Rio de Janeiro";
    e.Logradouro = "Estrada do Mapuá";
    e.Uf = "RJ";
    e.Tipo = te;//aqui estou mudando o tipo de endereço
    e.Id = 2;

    contexto.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
    contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Olá novamente Cigano,
Primeiro, muito obrigado por me ajudar!

Fiz a seguinte alteração:

_context.TipoEndereco.Attach(endereco.Tipo);
_context.Entry(endereco).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();

Faz sentido?

Comment: Sim, mas vou precisar atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Veja agora. Deve funcionar perfeitamente desta maneira.

Comment: Cigano,

Funcionou perfeitamente! Gostaria de te fazer uma pergunta:

Por que que tive que trazer o endereço do banco de dados? Para eu criar um contexto? Digo isso, porque estou utilizando uma console app e para classes que não possuem relacionamento, eu não precisei buscá-las no banco de dados igual busquei endereço.

Obrigado,

Comment: O Entity Framework usa o que chamamos de Contexto Observador: ele só sincroniza com o banco de dados as entidades que anexamos ao contexto, seja por pesquisa, seja por anexação, conforme expliquei. Isso tudo [eu falo no meu curso](http://codingcraft.com.br/2016/08/10/coding-craft-asp-net-mvc-e-asp-net-web-api-modulo-1-turma-de-10-de-setembro-de-2016/), se estiver interessado.

Comment: Já estou la. Procurando vagas para 2017...rs

Comment: [Só me chamar aqui](https://www.facebook.com/cigano.m.mendez). Faço aula individual também.